# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() arises when trying to find the max value

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

I know this question has been asked a lot, but the answers still doesn't make sense to me.

As given from the title, I am given the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-ff6e3e2d3ced> in <module>
      3     env = PIEnv()
      4     act = [1,2]
----> 5     env.step(act)
      6 

<ipython-input-32-cdba1f862773> in step(self, action)
     74             self.PV[i] = T  # Input the the Temperature Value
     75 
---> 76             [op, P, ierr] = self._pid(action, self.SP[i], self.PV[i], ierr)
     77 
     78             self.OP[i] = op

<ipython-input-32-cdba1f862773> in _pid(self, action, sp, pv, ierr, dt)
     52         if np.any(op >= opho) or np.any(op <= oplo):
     53             I -= action[1] * self.error * dt
---> 54             op = max(oplo, min(opho, op))
     55 
     56         return [op, P, I]

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

To my understand is that I need to use `a.any()` or `a.all()` due to `numpy.ndarray` if I am trying to do a Boolean comparison, like in line 52, but I don't understand why I need `a.any()` or `a.all()` for line 54, `op = max(oplo, min(opho, op))`. I am just trying to trying to get the max value. Can anyone shed some light?

Thanks!

Here is the code. This is a attribute.

```
    def _pid(self, action, sp, pv, ierr, dt=1):
    
        op0 = 0.0  # Initial Heater setting also considered the bias
        oplo = 0  # Heater Lower Limit
        opho = 100  # Heater Higher Limit
        
        self.error = sp - pv  # Error
        integral_error = ierr + action[1] * self.error * dt #Integral Error
        
        P = action[0] * self.error  # Proportional
        I = integral_error  # Integral
        
        op = op0 + P + I  # Calculates new output
        print(type(op>=opho))
        
        if np.any(op >= opho) or np.any(op <= oplo):
            I -= action[1] * self.error * dt
            op = max(oplo, min(opho, op))

        return [op, P, I]
```

Comment: The max and min function take an iterable - e.g. list, tuple, set, etc.

Comment: Note that you're using the builtins `min` and `max`, not the vectorized versions provided by `numpy`. The builtin `min` is attempting to make comparison of the form `if (row i) < (row j)`. See where the problem is? If you want to compute the minimum/maximum along an array axis, use `np.min`/`np.max` instead.

Comment: @It_is_Chris That's not a requirement. See the [builtins docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max). Both `min` and `max` can accept a variable number of arguments.

Comment: I guess the thing I am confused is that `op`, `oplo`, `opho` isn't a vector but an int/float, i think?. Unfortantely, when I try the `op = np.max([oplo, np.min([opho, op])])` I still get the same error. @Brian